# How can I create a proper do-while loop using Powershell

Tags: powershell, loops, do-while, bitlocker

I want the script to generate a random last group (`Key0`) and try to unlock the drive on each iteration with the concatenated string (`Key`), but is not working.
I execute the script and it just makes one try. It seems the while is not working.

```
Do {      
  $Hash0 = 0..5 | % {Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 9 }
  $Key0 = $Hash0 -join ""
  $Key  = "175615-666567-468105-046717-174922-139634-579799-"+$Key0
  manage-bde.exe -unlock H: -recoverypassword $Key >$null
  $Status = Get-BitlockerVolume -MountPoint "H:" 
} while($Status.CapacityGB -ne "0")
```

I'm not a Powershell expert.

Comment: `$Status.CapacityGB -ne "0"` -> `$Status.LockStatus -eq 'Locked'`, also `Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 9` never return 9, also digits group should be less then or equals to 720885 and be divisible by 11.

Comment: @PetSerAl I'd suggest posting that as an answer with an explanation.

Comment: So you're trying to brute force the bitlocker password?

Comment: PetSerAl, that's pretty neat. But the do while is still not working. It just tries once.

Comment: Indeed, TheMadTechnician.

Comment: That means it has something to do with the manage-bde.exe. I can run it and confirm working by replacing your manage-bde line with `$key | out-host`. Will look further into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a  Do-While loop the script block is executed at least once.

The While condition is evaluated after the script block has run. The script block will be repeated as long as the condition in the While statement is true.

Your statement While statement is

while($Status.CapacityGB -ne "0")

You want the do loop to execute while CapacityGB is not equal to 0

If the loop stopping it suggested that your while statement is evaluating to false which suggests the CapacityGB is zero.  I'd check what you're getting in the $status variable

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much, Richard. Changed `-ne` for `-eq`. Also, thank you to PetSerAl.